# Is there any equivalent in Java to swf?

Tags: java, flash

I am looking to create swf from Java, like ming from C/C++.

Is there anything like this for Java?

Answer (score 5):

JavaFX was actualy created for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

[TransformSWF](http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/index.html) from Flagstone Software is a SWF-generating library for Java.

It supports through Flash 7, is under reasonably active development, and has pretty good docs on its home page.  BSD licensed.

Its sister [TranslateSWF](http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/translate/index.html) is meant for compiling AS1 into SWF-embeddable bytecode from Java.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [OpenLaszlo](http://openlaszlo.org/)? not from java, but using java at least

Comment: OpenLaszlo is basically a precompiled SWF that lets you interact with it after the fact to build apps.  It's nothing like an equiv of ming for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaSWF - Macromedia Flash File Format](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaswf/)
JavaSWF provides a pure Java wrapper for the Macromedia Flash file format (known as SWF). It enables the parsing and generation of Flash content within Java applications and servlets.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use SWIG to generate a JNI wrapper for Ming.